# how to comprehensively assess three areas of cognition (attention, reaction-time, memory) on a daily, personal basis, preferably online,?

Tags: memory, test, attention, reaction-time

I am attempting to figure out a battery of tests that I can perform on myself on a daily/weekly basis to test whether any intervention I attempt on myself actually improves my cognitive performance.

From various sites, and with the awesome help of Seanny123, I narrowed it down to 3 variables I want to test for 1. attention 2. reaction-time 3. memory.

I found a few websites/software that seem to do this and seem legitimate

1. http://www.psytoolkit.org/
2. http://pebl.sourceforge.net/

However, even these software/website has multitude of tests and I am not sure which one to run.

Would you have any suggestions on which tests to run and using what software so as to comprehensively test these three areas (attention, reaction-time, memory) on a daily/weekly basis (totaly test time say ~ 15 min)?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try hypnosis. The mind needs rest although why this is is still a mystery. If you can put a person into "sleep mode" then you have a very reliable "beginners mode" for cognition.

Comment: What specific cognitive or psychological thing are you trying to measure?

Comment: @user14394... what?

Comment: @Seanny123, I know of various methodologies such as exercise/meditation/intermittent fasting/nootropics which are supposed to improve cognition. I am not 100% sure whether they specifically improve 1 area of cognition or all areas. In general I found from websites like (cambridgebrainsciences.com), that they classify all the tests into 1. attention 2. reaction-time and 3. memory. I guess those are the 3 areas I am trying to measure.

I found 2 websites other than the one I mentioned above 1. http://pebl.sourceforge.net/ 2. http://www.psytoolkit.org/.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions which tests to use and which website seems more legit?

Comment: @alpha_989 your question kind of exploded in terms of scope. Your asking for free reliable tests in these three areas. But you're also asking for the effects of various interventions on these three areas. I would recommend breaking up your question into smaller, easier to answer questions. (:

Comment: @Seanny123, Thanks for your reply, Sean :) I see what you mean. Since these tests are for personal testing, and ideally I would like to maximize all three areas, the mechanism doesnt matter too much at this point. It maybe that even these 3 areas have multiple sub-categories, so it maynot be possible to completely measure all three areas on a regular basis.

So would you be able to recommend a few freely available and scientifically validated tests (websites) for the 3 areas, which cover maybe 80% of all the subcategories of attention, memory and reaction-time?

Comment: For practical purposes, i would like to restrict the amount of time required for testing to ~ 15min for the whole battery.

Comment: Thanks for following up! If you were to edit your question to ask about how to comprehensively assess those three areas (attention, reaction-time, memory) on a daily, personal basis, preferrably online, I would happily upvote it. Do you know how to edit your question? (:

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. I will change the original question.. :)

Comment: @Seanny123, let me know if the change I made is clear enough..Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sweet. This question is still at risk of being closed as too broad according to some other people I was chatting to. After some thought, I think it's because some of the terms are still a bit vague. "Reaction time" is simple enough, but what exactly do you mean by "attention" and "memory". There's lots of types of those two things. Do you mean "working", "long term" or another form of memory? When you mean attention, do you mean the ability to focus for long periods of time or to notice things while doing another task? The Wikipedia article on both these topics might help.

Comment: Also, I just want to thank you for working with me on this question. This site is really strict about question appropriateness, but that's just because we want both the asker and the answerer to feel like their time is being respected. We don't want the asker to get silly answers and no answerer wants to feel like they're shooting in the dark.